# Using mp4 Video as Background using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, mp4, movie

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to display a video. It is working but I have a couple of issues. What I want to do is have certain parts of the video clickable and would play other videos (think old point and click games).

**Issues 1:**
If I double tap the video it changes scale, how can I disable this? I used

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] setUserInteractionEnabled:false]; // I'm using cocos2D
```

and

```
[moviePlayerController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
[moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

But I still can double tap to change scale.

**Issues 2:** I want to get the tap location. I haven't done anything yet but thinking of using `GestureRecognizer`, is that the correct way to do it?

Thanks :-)